# Rails TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a tag to a shop from the create a shop form.
For that i'm using nested attributes, but i get the following error:

**No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**

**Extracted source (around line #492):**

```rb
   association.target
 else
   attribute_ids = attributes_collection.map { |a| a["id"] || a[:id] }.compact
   attribute_ids.empty? ? [] : association.scope.where(association.klass.primary_key => attribute_ids)
 end
```

My code is:

**Shop.rb**

```rb
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :shop_tags ,  dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :shop_tags
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

**shops_controller.rb**

```rb
  def create
    @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
    # scaffold code 
  end

    def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(
        :longitude, :latitude, :name, :description, :state, :address, 
        tags_attributes:[:name, :id])
    end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @shop , local: true, scope: "shop") do |form| %>
  #the first part of the form
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= form.fields_for :tags_attributes do |form|  %>
          <%= form.label :name, %>
          <%= form.text_field :name ,class:'form-control' %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

i tried changing the field_for `:tags_attributes` for `:tags` or `:tag` but i get a unpermited param error.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you've pasted the wrong text where you wanted to paste the error. Also, it'd be nice if you'd properly capitalize your sentences as a courtesy to those trying to help you :)

Comment: Thank you, first time posting , i get bit nervous. i' going to edited :)

Comment: Can you show us what's inside the `attributes_collection` variable?

Comment: #<Enumerator: ["redcompra"]:map> , 'redcompra' was the tag I used in the form

Comment: I guess the problem is with `attributes_collection`, each of its element my be array, not hash in order to use `attributes_collection.map { |a| a["id"] || a[:id] }`. Also, in the form, it should be `<%= form.fields_for :tags_attributes do |tag_form|  %>` to differentiate with the `form` variable above

Comment: Where does `attributes_collection` come from?
It looks like it is not a Hash. A bit confusing it does not complain about the String access first.

Comment: Best would be for you to install debugger (I use `pry-rails`, put `binding.pry` breakpoint one line above `attribute_ids = attributes_collection.map` (if that's the line throwing exceptions), reload the page and in the debugger see what's inside the `attributes_collection` and how you need to update to mapper to do what you need.